# How to create 2 groups from 1

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have one large group of data and each row which pertains to one animal and its size. 
So per row I know the size of the animal, here is an example:

```
    |Animal #  |  Size  |
    |-------------------|
    |1         |  23.5  |
    |-------------------|
    |2         |  78.4  |
    |-------------------|
    |3         |  22.7  |
    |-------------------|
```

Total about 400 animals

How could I create 2 groups based on the size? I want to partition this data into 2 groups but am unsure which stat test would let me do this? At what threshold do I partition by?

Thoughts:

- Gaussian mixture model
- Thought about ANOVA but that doesn't help because I cant figure out how to make 2 groups

Comment: What is the reason for creating two size groups? Do you want a 'large' animal and a 'small' animal group? Grouping variables of interest should be based on theory or concept, but it will almost always be arbitrary. An example of this would be grouping the variable temperature (in Fahrenheit) by Below Freezing (<= 32 degrees)/Above Freezing (> 32 degrees).

Answer (score 1):

*Visualize*. Beats any statistic if you can convince your users visually.

An algorithm such as [Jenks Natural Breaks Optimization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) will work, but may return bogus results if the data doesn't have k clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a statistical test to group them?  If the sizes are as divergent as your 3 example points seem, perhaps just plot them all together to look for two groups.  In R, if you like:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1066)
eggs <- rnorm(100, 20, 3)
spam <- rnorm(300, 75, 9)
qplot(c(eggs,spam))
```

Then visually assess where a good cut-point would be, which in that data set would be around 35.

If you're set on using an algorithmic threshold however, you could use cut-point analysis, but that comes with several caveats (overfitting, inflation of Type I, etc).  They are detailed in this [paper](http://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/biostat-79pdf/doc-10027230).  In short, it details a method of finding a dividing line between two (imposed) categories given a continuous covariate.  For your case, a logistic regression would be a likely way to do it.

However, using cutpoint on this might be like trying to kill a fly with a sledgehammer.  I'd plot it and see what it looks like.